# synapse httpsend through proxy server

Tags: delphi, proxy, ararat-synapse

I have a routine that currently uses

httpgettext to send two urls out to google..

The first with the maps key
and the second to get some distance calculations with is returned as a JSON object...

It all worked fine but now the client wants it to go through a proxy server.

I have tried modifying code that was on synapse knowledge base but i just get a bad response...

The code looks like this that works no proxy...

```
buildstring:='http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v2&key=ASASASASASASASAS-AAAA';
httpgettext(buildstring,myoutput);
buildstring:='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin='+trim(start_postcode)+'&destination='+trim(end_postcode)+'&sensor=false';
httpgettext(buildstring,myoutput);
```

How do I get the same response but through a proxy?

The google maps key above is fake - and will not work - you need to use your own.

When I tried modifying an example the first request came back OK the second one came back with a 400 bad request.

With thanks in advance
Phil Hutchinson

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue?
I looked at the source code demos supplied and if I create a type of httpsend and put the proxy info in and send the request, the first one works.

The second request fails - so it must be something to do with the htppsend method leaving some rubbish in the type.  If I destroy it and send it again it works fine.

Not the perfect solution but it works!